# Sound modification - time/frequency domain

Tags: fourier-analysis, python, fast-fourier-transform

I've been trying to modify the sound intensity (volume) of a snare sample via python code.

Basically, I used two approaches:

- Multiplying the time signal by a negative exponential term, i.e. e^-3t.
- Take the Fourier transform, multiplying it by a decimal value lesser than one and applying the inverse Fourier transformation.

Both the results are a noisy unpleasant sound, different of the original one.
I plot some graphics to evaluate the wave format, taking a totally inaccurate eye analysis, the data seem similar to the original one.

The code can be found on my [github](https://github.com/andrehrema/sound_processing/blob/master/sound_processing.ipynb).

I have two questions:

- How can I approach this problem in a better way?
- Would correlation be a good parameter to analyze the similarities between the results and the original sample?

Comment: Your first approach is applying an exponential-shape volume envelope to the sample, so I'd expect the result to start at the original volume and rapidly decrease in volume. Your second approach is equivalent to decreasing the volume by a constant factor (since the Fourier transform is a linear operator, multiplying by a constant has the same effect in the frequency domain as in the time domain). If you're getting unpleasant noise from either of these, it might be an implementation problem rather than a theoretical one.

Comment: Have you tried an FFT+IFFT with no other modification of the array? Sometimes the transforms are defined so that this multiplies the data by a constant rather than leaving it unchanged. This would explain unpleasant noise (clipping).